# Powershell : Why I cannot use ForEach-Object to modify elements?

Tags: powershell, foreach, iterator

I've got an array definition:

```
> $a={"abc","xyz","hello"}
```

Then, using foreach to modify it, but seems original elements are not changed:

```
> foreach($i in $a){$i="kkk"+$i}
> $a
> "abc","xyz","hello"
```

Why foreach loop doesn't modify elements?
Then I tried to use ForEach-Object, this time, it doesn't even run:

```
> $a|%{$_=$_+"kkk"}
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:1 char:6
+ $a|%{$_=$_+"kkk"}
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Does this has any syntax error? Or my understanding is incorrect?

Answer (score 14):

You don't have an array in `$a`, you have a `[ScriptBlock]`. Curly braces `{}` denote a script block in PowerShell.

The array operator is `@()`.

This is the cause of the error in the second example.

```psh
$a=@("abc","xyz","hello")

foreach($i in $a) {
    $i = "zzz" + $i
}

$a | % { $_ += "zzz" }
```

However, this still will not work, because `$i` and `$_` are copies, not references back to the original array location.

Instead, you can iterate over the array using a regular `for` loop:

```psh
for( $i = 0 ; $i -lt $a.Count ; $i++ ) {
    $a[$i] += "zzz"
}
```

In this example you can see that in the loop body, you are referring directly to the array in `$a` and modifying its actual value.

Also note that `ForEach-Object` (`%`) returns a value (or all of the values returned from the block), so you could also do this:

```psh
$a = $a | % { "qqq" + $_ }
```

However this is forming a brand new array and assigning it to `$a`, not really modifying the original.